# how can i get the first and last word of element in array php

Tags: php

i was trying to get the first and last word of element in array,
i've tried this code but it didn't get the proper result

```
    foreach(unserialize($q['qlite']) as $qkey => ql)
    {
         foreach($ql as zp)
         {
              $response = $zp[0];
              echo '$response';
         }
    }
```

and this is the result i got
array(
     [0]  => michael jordan is the best player of all time
     [23] => 23
)

what i want is to get the first value "michael" and the last value "time"

Comment: Split the sentence into an array of words, then get the first and last element out of that array.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($ql as $zp)
{
   $response = $zp[0];
   $words = explode(' ', $zp[0]);

   echo $words[0];
   echo $words[count($words) - 1];
}
```

As explained in a comment, you need to split the string to get each word and then return the first and last of the array created by the split.

Comment: in general this will work for more complex situations you may need a regular expression  `preg_split()` and the word boundary `\b`

Comment: Yeh, the answer I gave is based on the string output the OP gave. But for more complex strings regex would indeed be needed.